# Twilio Message Segments

Tags: sms, twilio, twilio-functions

I am using Twilio services for one of my projects.I wanted to have suggestions of how I can optimize my message sending, i.e currently when I send a message it goes in 6 segments which cost me more.Is there any way through which I decrease the number of segments in the SMS.

Thanks in advance

-Tapas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

The length of a single SMS message is usually 160 characters. Initially, to reduce the number of segments you are sending, you should look at shortening your message.

Under certain circumstances messages may have a limit of 70 characters. This happens when you use characters that are outside of the regular GSM character set, this could be things like emoji, Kanji or other symbol style languages and even accented characters. You can learn more about this in this blog post on [sending Unicode characters by SMS](https://www.twilio.com/blog/2015/08/common-sms-problems-unicode-twilio.html).

In this case, you can possibly reduce the number of segments by limiting your character set to the basic GSM characters. If you need unicode characters because of the languages in which you are sending messages require them, then this may not help though.